# Error when converting pandas dataframe to xarray dataset

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dataset, netcdf, python-xarray

I started with a NetCDF file which I converted to a dataset using the xarray module. I then converted that dataset to a dataframe and manipulated it using pandas (resampled the dataframe and created a new one).

I'm now trying to convert the new dataframe to an xarray dataset, and then back again to a NetCDF. When I use the command

```
ds = xarray.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)
```

I get the error:

```
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

As the error likely results from the reshaping and resampling of the dataframe and there are a number of operations performed on it - I am struggling to reproduce it without providing all the original files and code.

I'm just wondering if there's something obvious that I'm missing and if this can be solved...

EDIT:

I got around this by using

```
df.to_xarray()
```

which did not bring up an error, but I would still like this bug to be ironed out for other users.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your DataFrame, e.g., `df.head()`? That would help clarify what your data looks like.

Comment: sorry for delay, snippet of the df and reindexed df here: https://image.ibb.co/kFTkkw/Capture.png

Comment: It's surprising that `.to_xarray()` works. On a pandas.DataFrame, `df.to_xarray()` should be exactly equivalent to `xarray.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)`.

Comment: I've re-ran the code and yes you're correct they both work. I'm not sure what's happened to bring about the error but now I can't replicate it! Thanks for your help and apologies for mix-up.